# Sometimes it takes a long time for the app to start

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my iOS application, i see that many times the application is stuck on the splash screen for to long and it takes some time for it to start.

I paused all threads and there is no thread running in my code, only in the cocoa code.

What might cause it?

Comment: It is probably just the debugger starting up, attaching, etc.  Or does it happen even without the debugger?

Comment: happens even without debugger

Comment: Then could you post a snapshot of your running threads when it is in this state?  Sometimes SpringBoard is just busy and can't launch your app quickly (thread starvation).  If there really is no code being executed by you then you have no control over it.

Comment: I recall one project to have a long launch time (before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets called), it had quite a lot of linked frameworks which I believe was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have written a lots of code in your

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
}
```

method which is the first method to be called when application start running.Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing too much in the app delegate. Change that code to occur in the first vc called.